# hadoop how to merge files created by totalorderpartitioner?

Tags: sorting, hadoop, hdfs

I am looking into total order sorting in hadoop using TotalOrderPartitioner. The problem is that 
the TotalOrderPartitioner  generates multiple files and I need a single sorted file. I have looked at some examples which use `hadoop fs -cat output/part-r-*` to merge all the files together. However, I am not sure if it is guaranteed that `cat` will read files in the same order everytime. Is there are sure shot way of merging all the sorted files together to produce one large sorted file ?

Comment: `*` will expand out the files in order, so `hadoop fs -cat output/part-r-*` should work.